# Change the reported screen resolution inside Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpcom

I would like to change the screen resolution that Firefox reports to websites.

For example, if my resolution is 1280x768, I want it to be reported as 800x600 to the website.

How is that possible? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

this greasemonkey script can do that:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name        testa
// @namespace   testscreen
// @include     http://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// @run-at      document-start
// ==/UserScript==
delete window.screen;
window.__defineGetter__('screen',function(){
          s=[];
          s['width']=768;s['height']=1024;
          return s; 
})
```